# white line between svg and other elements

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

I have very simple svg with just one color and three polygon points.

In Chrome on some width's there is a white line before th svg which should not be there:

[image]

On top there is a div with the same color. The svg even overlaps to the div with the same color with `margin-bottom -10px;` but that white line appears all the time:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1920 145" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1920 145;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#262120;}
</style>
<g>
    <polygon class="st0" points="1920,145 0,0 1920,0    "/>
</g>
</svg>
```

What's the catch here?

Comment: Not sure if it is stroke or not but can you try adding stroke: #262120; to your css class

Comment: Sounds like it could be similar to how images can have a pixel gap sometimes. What happens if you give the svg a style of vertical-align: top?

Comment: antialiasing perhaps?

Comment: It could also potentially be antialiasing from scaling down the svg.

Comment: None of the classic tricks seem to work :( I guess this is an antialiasing issue. Especially since it only occurs on certain viewport width's.

Comment: Wondering if you ever got to the bottom of this?

Comment: No. I couldn't figure it out. I assume it is some sort of antialiasing issue. But that's just an idea

Answer (score 1):

This could be down to the fact that all html elements are set with a line height of normal in css.

```
line-height: 0;
```

may solve this issue ‍♂️